# Updating nested property value via a string path using expression

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

## The Problem to solve

I want to be able to update the property `prop` using the fictive method `Update`.
To do so, i would like to call the method like this:

```
Root obj = /* ... */;
Update(obj, "sub/sub/prop", "foobar");
```

How would i eg. build some Expression tree to do this?

## Scenario

```
class Sub2
{
    public string prop { get; set; }
}
class Sub1
{
    public Sub2 sub { get; set; }
}
class Root
{
    public Sub1 sub { get; set; }
}
class Main
{
    //...
    void Update(object obj, string navigation, object newval) { /* magic */ }
}
```

## Full Problem

I need to be able to serialize single fields from some object (already solved, method head `public void Serialize<TProperty>(T obj, Stream s, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> exp)`) and update a corresponding field on a server application.
Only that field is allowed to be updated, some classes are nested way too deep to allow for solutions like "just use some ID stuff and a switch to then put the value into the right field" which is why this approach was chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got it finally solved myself

```
public void Update1(T obj, string[] input, object newval)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    var param1 = Expression.Parameter(t);
    Expression exp = param1;
    foreach (var it in input.Skip(1).Take(input.Length - 2))
    {
        var minfo = t.GetProperty(it).GetGetMethod();
        exp = Expression.Call(exp, minfo);
        t = minfo.ReturnType;
    }
    var lastprop = t.GetProperty(input.Last());
    var minfoset = lastprop.GetSetMethod();
    var variableexp = Expression.Variable(lastprop.PropertyType);
    exp = Expression.Call(exp, minfoset, variableexp);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(exp, param1, variableexp);
    lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke(obj, newval);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion to navigate down to the property to update. This code expects all the properties along the path to be not `NULL`, if you can have nulls then it should be easy to have some checking code to handle this case (throw an Exception, etc.).

```
void Update(object obj, string navigation, object newval)
{
    var firstSlash = navigation.IndexOf("/");
    if (firstSlash < 0)
    {
        obj.GetType().GetProperty(navigation).SetValue(obj, newval);
    }
    else
    {
        var header = navigation.Substring(0, firstSlash);
        var tail = navigation.Substring(firstSlash + 1);
        var subObj = obj.GetType().GetProperty(header).GetValue(obj);
        Update(subObj, tail, newval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gonna compare it speedwise tomorrow, tbh... not even thought about that possiblility

Comment: Method i answered myself is 4x faster according to my tests

Comment: That's cool, I'm just trying to get a higher rep :) hadn't considered speed. I've just upvoted your answer

Comment: "just trying to get a higher rep" Here! Have a +1 because I'm stealing this code 